# Careers layout is broken on IE7/Vista

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

So I thought I'd check out the [new look of Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

And, well, let's just say it doesn't work well with IE7. I can post a screenshot if I can find an image-sharing site that's not blocked, but it should be pretty easy to verify.

Among other things:

- The **For candidates** / **For employers** leaks up onto the "Does the world really need another careers site?"
- The gray footer appears at the bottom of the *first* page -- i.e., the page has a scrollbar and I can scroll *past* the footer to find the rest of the content (although some of it is hidden underneath the footer).
- The text in the gray footer is on a white background, so it's invisible.

Is this perhaps part of a secret plan to filter out anyone who uses outdated browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a secret plan. Well, if it were a secret plan, we wouldn't tell you.

We've resolved these issues, would you have another look? Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Yep, it looks like the picture in the blog now.